# Count on Spark Dataframe is extremely slow

Tags: scala, apache-spark, count, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I'm creating a new DataFrame with a handful of records from a Join.

```
val joined_df = first_df.join(second_df, first_df.col("key") ===
second_df.col("key") && second_df.col("key").isNull, "left_outer")
joined_df.repartition(1)
joined_df.cache()
joined_df.count()
```

Everything is fast (under one second) except the count operation. The RDD conversion kicks in and literally takes hours to complete. Is there any way to speed things up?

```
INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_63_140 stored as values in memory (estimated size 16.0 B, free 829.3 MB)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_63_140 in memory on 192.168.8.52:36413 (size: 16.0 B, free: 829.8 MB)
INFO Executor: Finished task 140.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 544). 4232 bytes result sent to driver
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 142.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 545, localhost, executor driver, partition 142, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6284 bytes)
INFO Executor: Running task 142.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 545)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 140.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 544) in 16 ms on localhost (executor driver) (136/200)
INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 200 blocks
INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 200 blocks
INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
```

Comment: Eevrything is fast under 1 second because no operation happens till you reach `count`. Read more about [Lazy Evaluation in Spark here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Everything is fast (under one second) except the count operation.

This is justified as follow : all operations before the `count` are called transformations and this type of spark operations are lazy i.e. it doesn't do any computation before calling an action (`count` in your example).

The second problem is in the `repartition(1)` :

keep in mind that you'll lose all the parallelism offered by spark and you computation will be run in one executor (core if your are in standalone mode), so you must remove this step or change **1** to a number propositional to the number of your CPU cores (standalone mode) or the number of executors (cluster mode).

> The RDD conversion kicks in and literally takes hours to complete.

If I understand correctly you would covert the `DataFrame` to an `RDD`, this is really a bad practice in spark and you should avoid such conversion as possible as you can.
this is because the data in `DataFrame` and `Dataset` are encoded using **special spark encoders** (it's called tungstant if I well remembered it) which take much less memory then the JVM serialization encoders, so such conversion mean that spark will change the type of your data from his own one (which take **much less memory** and let spark **optimize** a lot of commutations by just work the encoded data and not serialize the data to work with and then deserialize it) to the JVM data type and this why `DataFrame`s and `Dataset`s are very powerful than `RDD`s

Hope this help you

Comment: Why is the conversion of DataFrame to and RDD a bad practice? Aren't RDDs the underlying instances in Dataframes and Datasets?

Comment: this is because the data in `DataFrame` and `Dataset` are encoded using special spark encoders (it's called **tungstant** if I well remembered it)  which take **much less memory** then the JVM serialization encoders, so such conversion mean that spark will change the type of your data from his own one (which take much less memory and let spark optimize a lot of commutations by just work the encoded data and not serialize the data to work with and then deserialize it) to the JVM data type and this why `DataFrame`s and `Dataset`s are very powerful than `RDD`s.

Comment: Sometimes necessary still - zipWithIndex still

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the operations before `count` are "lazy" and only *register a transformation*, rather than actually *force a computation*.

When you call `count`, the computation is triggered. This is when Spark reads your data, performs all previously-registered transformations and calculates the result that you requested (in this case a `count`).

> The RDD conversion kicks in and literally takes hours to complete

I think the term "conversion" is perhaps a bit inaccurate. What is actually happening is that the `DataFrame` transformations you registered are translated into `RDD` operations, and these are applied to to the RDD that underlies your `DataFrame`. There is no conversion *per se* in the code you have given here.

As an aside, it is possible to explicitly convert a `DataFrame` to an `RDD` via the `DataFrame.rdd` property. As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45142970/5368910) this is generally a bad idea, since you lose some of the benefits (in both performance and API) of having well-structured data.

Comment: So, what is the way to compute it then in a faster way?